# How do I dismiss the keyboard in a custom keyboard?

Tags: swift, custom-keyboard, dismiss, resignfirstresponder

I would like to assign a key/button on my custom keyboard to dismiss/hide the keyboard. I can't seem to get any code to work.

I have tried:

```
self.view.resignFirstRespoder()

view.endEditing(true)
```

But nothing along these lines seems to work.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `dismissKeyboard()` function.

> Because a custom keyboard does not have access to the current text
>   input object, you cannot send it a resignFirstResponder() message (as
>   you would to dismiss the system keyboard when you are developing an
>   app with text entry). To dismiss the custom keyboard, call
>   dismissKeyboard() instead.

[Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiinputviewcontroller/1618196-dismisskeyboard).